# Not changed my custom switchers

Tags: jquery

I have custom checkboxes, and i want change they status, when select one checkbox, but it works on first step but on second no.

```
$("body").on("click", ".ID", function(event){
        var switcher = $(".ID");
        if(switcher.attr('checked')=="checked")
        {
            switcher.attr('checked', false);
            if(people!=null)
            {
                for(var i = 0; i<people.length;i++)
                {
                    $(".ID-"+people[i].id).attr('checked', false);
                    $(".ID-"+people[i].id).removeAttr('checked');
                    /*f(clickID>=1)
                    {
                        $(".ID-"+people[i].id).trigger('click');
                    }*/
                }
            }
            clickID++;
        }else{
            switcher.attr('checked', true);
            if(people!=null)
            {
                for(var i = 0; i<people.length;i++)
                {
                    $(".ID-"+people[i].id).attr('checked', true);
                    $(".ID-"+people[i].id).attr('checked', 'checked');
                    /*if(clickID>=1)
                    {
                        $(".ID-"+people[i].id).trigger('click');
                    }*/
                } 
            }
            clickID++;
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ArthurYakovlev/vha9h/6/

Comment: Do you mind to put this into a Fiddle? I don't see the `var` for `people`?

Comment: and add a few html please on your fiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ArthurYakovlev/vha9h/6/

Comment: I've added an answer, and updated the "Fiddle" with its link. Please let us know if what you're looking to get an answer on is to Select/Remove checks on your checkboxes, on a master checkbox's click event?

Comment: Look pls and thanks! Second steo does not work. In chrome

Comment: @Arthur Yakovlev Looking into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the jQuery [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) for `.attr()`:

*Nevertheless, the most important concept to remember about the checked attribute is that it does not correspond to the checked property. The attribute actually corresponds to the defaultChecked property and **should be used only to set the initial value of the checkbox.***

We can use `.prop()` or `.is()` in place of `.attr()`

Comment: Yes its true, i am use now prop with is. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").on("click", ".ID", function(event){
        var switcher = $(".ID");

        if (people !== null) {         
            for(var i = 0; i<people.length;i++)
            {
                $(".ID-"+people[i].id).prop("checked", switcher.is(':checked'));
            }
            //alert($(".ID-12").is(':checked'));
        }       
    });
```